# What's actually $S^k(M)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition, tensors

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ be an $R$-module.

Let $T(M)$ be the tensor algebra of $M$.

Then, what is $S(M)$ (symmetric algebra and $S^k(M)$?

Some articles define $S(M)$ as a quotient of the tensor algebra while others define $S(M)$ as a subalgebra of the tensor algebra. Wikiepdia article specifices the difference between two, but I completely don't understand that article since I'm completely not familar with symmetric algebra. What's the intrinsic difference between two? (Q1)

Moreover, I am really uncomfotable with the definition of symmetric algebra as a quotient of the tensor algebra when dealing with $k^{th}$-symmetric power.

To be specific, my text(Dummi&Foote) defines it via graded ring. So that he defines $\{S^k(M)\}$ as a sequence of abelian groups whose direct sum of $T(M)/I$ where $I$ is an ideal generated by $v\otimes w - w\otimes v$ and other properties that asserts $T(M)$ is a graded ring. I'm uncomfortable with this definition since $S^k$ cannot be well-defined. There maybe two sequences $\{A_n\}$ and $\{B_n\}$ satisfying the hypothesis of the definition of graded ring. How do I exactly and dry-formally define $S^k$? (Q2)

Great thanks in advance. Please help me!

Comment: I don't understand the question.  D&F prove that $T(M)$ is a ring.  They then define $C(M)$ to be the ideal in $T(M)$ generated by the set $\{m_1 \otimes m_2 - m_2 \otimes m_1\}$, which they show is a graded ideal.  They then define $S(M) = T(M)/C(M)$, so by Proposition 33 p. 444, $S^k(M) = T^k(M)/C^k(M)$ where $C^k(M)  = C(M) \cap T^k(M)$.  Proposition 40 p. 453 shows that the two definitions of symmetric algebra that you state are isomorphic.  What is your question?

Comment: @SpamIAm Proposition 40 states that they are isomorphic when $char(R)=0$.